# .htaccess. Как сделать редирект с https://mydomain.com/index.php/catalog/knifes на https://mydomain.com/catalog/knifes

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Как сделать редирект с https://mydomain.com/index.php/catalog/knifes на https://mydomain.com/catalog/knifes и другими похожими случаями, когда index.php идёт вначале, а затем идут другие сегменты маршрута?

```
RewriteEngine On

Redirect 301 /instagram/IGTV /instagram/igtv

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php

# С www на без www

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain\.su$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mydomain.su/$1 [R=301,L]

# Без слэша

#RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# с index.html/php на главную

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.(php|html|htm)\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.(php|html|htm)$ https://mydomain.su/$1 [R=301,L]

# Убрать ? после /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /\?\d*\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^ https://mydomain.su/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[^\s]+\s+[^?]*?\?
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
#RewriteRule .? %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule .? https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если нужно захватить все что после index.php то рул будет таким:

```
RewriteRule ^/index\.php(.*)$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать так:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: Добавил свой .htaccess файл в вопрос. К сожалению, код, который Вы предоставили, у меня уже имеется, но это не спасает.

Answer (score 0):

А что если...

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы реализовывали url адреса(или может пути, я не знаю как это назвать "catalog/knifes") через express в nodejs, то стоит просто добавить следующее:

```js
app.get("/", function(request, response) {
    response.render("index");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
```